# How to re-write df["column_A"]` to only return values of a column_A for where the values of another column are equal to '3'?

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new to python, pandas etc.

**Context:**

My dataframe 'listCoords' which looks as such:

```
Date/Time              Lat                   Lon                   Threat
2019-01-20 06:00:00,   -10.792921094981814,  20.191716715339687,    2
2019-01-20 06:05:00,   -11.798684405083584,  21.162881454312586,    3
2019-01-20 06:05:00,   -10.798684405083584,  19.162881454312586,    1
2019-01-20 06:05:00,   -11.798684405083584,  20.145381454312586,    1
```

Currently I use all the "lat" values per: `lat = listCoords["Lat"]`.
Now I want to have a `lat_threat = listCoords["Lat"]` for where `listCoords["Threat"]=="3"`.

How do I re-write `lat = listCoords["Lat"]`, in order to get only the 'Lat' of where (Threat=="3") ?

Comment: listCoords[listCoords["Threat"]==3]["Lat"]

Comment: Thanks, when I add quotes before and after the 3 it works.

Comment: Sorry, didn't remember that your 3 is a string. Glad to help!

Comment: @jhso How would the architecture of this statement have to best change if I want to return values of a column_A for where the values of another column are equal to '3' AND at the same time the value of yet another column are '2'? Would this be correct --> `listCoords[(listCoords["Threat"]==3 & listCoords["Status"]==2)]["Lat"] `?

Comment: @jhso Oh never mind sir, I have it --> `listCoords[(listCoords["Threat"]=="3") & (listCoords["Status"]=="2")]["Lon"]`